# react test, how to test for unchecked state?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I have a test for using simulate.click, which tests for input checked. How would I test for when the input is unchecked?

```
    var input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(instance, "input");

    TestUtils.Simulate.click(input);

    var data = this.stubbed.getLastPublished();

    expect(data.topic === 'selected');
    expect(data.id === 1);
    expect(input.checked === true);
```

Comment: How about `expect(input.checked !== true);` or `expect(input.checked === false);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply I used:

```
TestUtils.Simulate.click(input, { target: {
        checked: false }
    });
```